# Prove $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

**The Problem:**

I want to prove $k\binom{n}{k} = n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ **algebraically**

**My Work So Far:**

$n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$

$= n(\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!})$ (By definition of $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$)

$= \frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k+1)!}$ (By the fact: $n*(n-1)! = n!$)

$= \frac{kn!}{k!(n-k+1)!}$ (By multiplying top and bottom by $k$)

**My Problem:**

I'm close, I just have to find a way to make  $(n-k+1)k! = k!(n-k)!$ and I'll have $LHS= RHS$ I'm having trouble doing this though, any suggestions?

Comment: There's an error in your second line.

Comment: What is the error? I'm pretty sure that's the definition of C(n,r).

Comment: The error is $\left( {n - 1 - \left( {k - 1} \right)} \right) = \left( {n - k} \right)$, not $\left( {n - k + 1} \right)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$n\left( \begin{gathered}
  n - 1 \\
  k - 1 \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) = n\frac{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}{{\left( {k - 1} \right)!\left( {n - k} \right)!}} = k\frac{{n!}}{{k!\left( {n - k} \right)!}} = k\left( \begin{gathered}
  n \\
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)$

Comment: Ahhhh so I messed up with the most basic step in my proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While your question explicitly asked for an algebraic proof, am adding this combinatorial proof because it should be pointed out when such identities are being proven.

Define a labelled subset of $U = \{1,\cdots, n\}$ to be a tuple $(l, S)$, where $l \in S$ and $S \subset U$. How many labelled subsets of size $k$ does $U$ have? There are two ways of enumerating all such sets:

1. Pick $l$ from $U$($n$ ways) and then pick $S - \{l\} \subset U$($\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ ways). The number of ways of doing this is $n * \binom{n-1}{k-1}$.
2. Pick $S$ from $U$($\binom{n}{k}$ ways) and then pick $l \in S$($k$ ways). The number of ways of doing this is $k * \binom{n}{k}$.

Thus, from $1$ and $2$ above, you have your required identity.